# How do I select 1 column from a SQL query which is ordered by date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a private messages model which has the columns: `sender_id`, `recipient_id`, `content`, and `created_at`.

I want to select the last 5 recipients I have messaged. However, I can't figure out how to narrow down the columns.

My current query is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT recipient_id, created_at FROM private_messages WHERE sender_id = :user_id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5
```

I can't get rid of the created_at column since it's necessary for the `ORDER BY`.  I must be missing something, but I'm not entirely sure what it is.

Comment: I figured out a really hacky alternative way of doing it using subqueries.  For anyone wondering, this is what I did: SELECT DISTINCT recipient_id FROM (SELECT recipient_id FROM private_messages WHERE sender_id = :user_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS recipients LIMIT 5

Answer (score 2):

....I can't get rid of the created_at column since it's necessary for the ORDER BY.

No.

A column in Order By cluase is not necessary to be present in SELECT column list.
You can omit `created_at` column in SELECT list of your query . Rest of your query will work fine.

Check this **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e8d71/1)** where above fact is shown.

Comment: weird, I took out the DISTINCT and created_at and it works just fine.  However, when I add the DISTINCT back in, I get this error: PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Comment: Not entirely sure if that's correct, I could have messaged the same user 5 times.  Without the distinct, I would get that recipient_id 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the below:

```
SELECT TOP 5  recipient_id
FROM private_messages 
WHERE sender_id = :user_id 
GROUP BY recipient_id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I believe you don't need created_at in your select to use it in an order by clause. This might depend on which database system you are using tho, in SQL server it will allow this.

Comment: I'm using PostGreSQL.. Syntax error: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "5"

Comment: yeah in PostGreSQL remove the top 5 and add the limit 5 back in at the end.

Comment: Same error as the other response: column "private_messages.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

try this: SELECT DISTINCT recipient_id, created_at FROM private_messages WHERE sender_id = :user_id GROUP BY recipient_id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: I get this error:  column "private_messages.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: distinct and group by will do the same thing in this situation, and if you do a group by you will have to group by id and date in your example

Comment: try removing distinct since group by clause is used

Answer (score 0):

try:
SELECT recipient_id FROM(SELECT recipient_id,MAX(created_at) as created_at FROM private_messages WHERE sender_id = :user_id GROUP BY recipient_id)a ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5;

Answer (score 0):

You can't omit the column. This has been added to the SQL standard some time ago.

> for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Quoted from  [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/27009.1171559417@sss.pgh.pa.us) (message from Tom Lane.)

> there's actually a definitional reason for it.  Consider
>
> SELECT DISTINCT x FROM tab ORDER BY y;
>
> For any particular x-value in the table there might be many different y
>   values.  Which one will you use to sort that x-value in the output?
>
> Back in SQL92 they avoided this problem by specifying that ORDER BY
>   entries had to reference output columns. SQL99 has some messy verbiage
>   that I think comes out at the same place as our restriction

For example, Oracle does not enforce this rule (10g or 11g).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 WITH t AS ( SELECT max(created_at) AS created_at, recipient_id  FROM messages 
 GROUP BY recipient_id  )

 SELECT created_at, recipient_id   FROM t ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5
```